# Fibonacci Number using Recursion

Tags: java, data-structures

First of all this is not assignment, but still if you feel the same kindly close the tab.

This morning I was trying to find the all Fibonacci numbers using recursion, but I am not getting the right solution.

Required Output is : Number 10 => Fibonacci number is 2, 3, 5, 8

```
long res=0;
FibonacciTest test = new FibonacciTest();
for(int i=1;i<=num;i++) {
    System.out.println(" "+test.getRecursiveFibonacci(num));
}

public long getRecursiveFibonacci(long number) {
    if ( number <=2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return getRecursiveFibonacci(number-1) + getRecursiveFibonacci(number -2);
}
```

Can you please help me on this.

Comment: I would like to point out that currently your output would be the sum of your fibonacci numbers rather than a list of those. So you might want to think about using String as a return value.

Comment: What's it doing wrong?

Comment: System.out.println(" "+test.getRecursiveFibonacci(num));

This line should print the fibonacci numbers for any given number 'num'. However, the output is the addition of every fibonacci number of this number due to this line:
    return getRecursiveFibonacci(number-1) + getRecursiveFibonacci(number -2);

the return datatype of getRecursiveFibonacci is "long". Combining the two with "+" results in addition.

Comment: That is what i am not getting.. How?

Comment: @ChristianKullmann Are you sure?  It looks fine to me.

Comment: Your recursive function is returning the sum of two recursive calls. Not returning the largest value within an upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
test.getRecursiveFibonacci(i)
```

instead of

```
test.getRecursiveFibonacci(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

note that fibonacci no. upto 10 are 1,1,2,3,5,8 so if you want to print fibonacci no less then n , then there are much better ways but if you want to do by your own way & according to recursion , then just update the code as given :

```
long res=0;
FibonacciTest test = new FibonacciTest();
    for(int i=1;i<=num;i++) {
         int j=test.getRecursiveFibonacci(i);
         if(j<=num)
             System.out.println(" "+j);
         else break;
    }

public long getRecursiveFibonacci(long number) {
    if ( number <=2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return getRecursiveFibonacci(number-1) + getRecursiveFibonacci(number -2);
}
```

note: if you don't want to print 1,1 then start the for loop with i=3